# Analytic equation of plane

Tags: analytic-geometry

If we want to specify the equation of a plane that goes through 3 different points we have the following determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}x-a1&y-a2&z-a3\\b1-a1&b2-a2&b3-a3\\c1-a1&c2-a2&c3-a3 \end{vmatrix}=0$$ which comes from the mixed product of the vectors. But we can also use the following determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}x&y&z&1\\a1&a2&a3&1\\b1&b2&b3&1\\c1&c2&c3&1 \end{vmatrix}=0$$
How can we go from the first equation to the second one?

Comment: This is a formula that comes from *projective geometry*: the `1`s in the last column are the 4th coordinates in projective $3$-space for points at finite distance.

Comment: So there in no way of transforming the first equation to the second? Is it just another approach?

Comment: You can; just subtract the second row from the first, third and fourth rows, and expand the determinant by the last column.